# Is there any downside to always declaring some default bad chars when generating exploits?

Tags: metasploit, shellcode

When setting the bad chars for shell code, is there any downside to just assuming that you should mark \x00 and \x0a as bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For shellcode the only potential issue is size constraints. But assuming null bytes are bad is a bad habit. You might mistakenly think a crash is not exploitable because the only viable pop pop ret/ROP addresses start with a null byte.

Determining exact bad bytes isn't too time consuming and I always recommend doing it as it can save time if you need to troubleshoot your shellcode.

Comment: +1. Null bytes are not bad in every situation. It is only bad in overflowing a string input where it is treated as a terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Not generally, since NULL and Line Feed are always bad chars. But size of your code will increase. I would not automatize this tho.

For example in IA32 Assembler you can replace the instruction

```
B8 01000000    MOV EAX,1          // Set the register EAX to 0x000000001
```

With

```
33C0           XOR EAX,EAX        // Set the register EAX to 0x000000000
40             INC EAX            // Increase EAX to 0x00000001
```

This even takes fewer bytes to encode, but generally it will be more tedious to replace chars as the number of bad chars increases.